# Repeat numbers in List/IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list, e.g.

```
List<int> List1 = new List<int>{1, 5, 8, 3, 9};
```

What is a simple way of repeating the elements in the list to obtain {1, 1, 5, 5, 8, 8, 3, 3, 9, 9}?

The reason I need this is that I am plotting the elements in the list and need to make a "step plot".

Comment: Why don't you just assign the current value to a local variable and use that twice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var list2 = List1.SelectMany(x => new []{x, x}).ToList();
```

Comment: might want to make the lambda `x => new[]{x,x}` to save the overhead of another `List` for each element. +1 anyway though ;)

Comment: @Jamiec For all intents and purposes, there is very little difference in overhead between the two. They would both allocate an array of size 2 for each element. You can try use `x => Enumerable.Repeat(2, x)` instead. This could have lower GC overhead.

Comment: @Aron, I've made you comment into an answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/21403456/659190, its a better solution, although you have the parameters reversed.

Answer (score 3):

I would create (extension) method which enumerates source and yields each item required number of times:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> RepeatItems<T>(this IEnumeable<T> source, int count)
{
    foreach(var item in source)
       for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
          yield return item;
}
```

Thus you will avoid creating huge number of arrays. Usage:

```
var result = List1.RepeatItems(2).ToList();
```

If you need just to duplicate items, then solution is even more simple:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> DuplicateItems<T>(this IEnumeable<T> source)
{
    foreach(var item in source)
    {
        yield return item;
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

Usage of DuplicateItems extension:

```
var result = List1.DuplicateItems().ToList();
```

Also if you will only enumerate result, then you don't need to convert it to list. If you will not modify (add/remove) items from result, then converting it to array is more efficient.

Comment: `RepeatItems` looks like a duplication of `Enumerable.Repeat` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348899(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Jodrell no, `RepeatItems` creates sequence where each item of original sequence is repeated. Default `Repeat` just creates sequence from single item which is repeated

Answer (score 2):

Taken from the comments above,

```
var sequence2 = List1.SelectMany(x => Enumerable.Repeat(x, 2));
```

is a better solution becuase it avoids pointless allocation of memory. It would also be simpler to change to `n` repetitions where the variation in overhead would become more significant.

Comment: I don't know about memory usage, I could believe that a two-element array is smaller than the iterator created by `Enumerable.Repeat`.

Comment: @Rawling But a two element array AND its iterator is bigger than the iterator created by `Enumerable.Repeat`. Not to mention there is the overhead of writing the array in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

It's you're trying to reduce memory allocations:

```
// Pre-allocate the space to save time
List<int> dups = new List(List1.Count * 2);

// Avoid allocating an enumerator (hopefully!)
for(int i=0; i<List1.Count; i++)
{
  var value = List1[i];
  dups.Add(value);
  dups.Add(value);
}
```

It's not Linq, but it's memory efficient